# How can creepers spawn in my house during broad daylight?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I was playing survival, I was out collecting dirt to create a small flat area to try to get slimes to spawn, then when I went inside my house **(Note: It hadn't gone through a night cycle yet.)**, there was a creeper right there and it exploded.

I am so angry it's not even funny. I was thinking since when can creepers spawn in it. I have thought a couple way but not sure is it true. Here is the possibility in my mind.

- A. Broad Daylight.
- B. Inside a building,
- C. Especially when the building has torches everywhere? (My house is a 12 x 10 x 12 block house.)

Someone needs to give me an explanation.

Here's the 1st floor

[image]

Here's the second

[image]

Comment: Did you leave any doors open?

Comment: No, i... didn't.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the house?

Comment: the inside of the house?

Comment: All it needs is one block where the light level is low enough to allow a hostile mob to spawn.

Comment: How dark is it inside? Best way to prevent spawns is to put light everywhere!!

Comment: Some windows might help?

Comment: Please provide an image of the inside of your house

Comment: Ok.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostile mobs spawns when light level drops below 7. It just take one single block in your house that meets the spawning criteria for mobs to spawn. So, be sure to check the light level or simply have sufficient lighting

Comment: My house is torch infested

Comment: And how do i check lighting (this is minecraft windows 10 edition on console)